# Error VSP1804: Unable to open file. The file format appears to be invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio 2012 when the instrumentation profiler is trying to create the report after profiling:

`Error VSP1804: Unable to open file. The file format appears to be invalid`

The profiler creates the report if it is run on like small data set, but it seems like this error is showing up if the profiler was running a little bit longer on a larger data set. Does anyone know what this error means or have seen this error?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this make sure all the projects are running in 32 bit (x86).
In your project properties: Properties --> Build --> Platform target --> x86.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/abf4ae19-114f-492a-9191-28df94a6be1f